# find Interval of Convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to find the interval of convergence for the power series $(-2x)^n/e^{2n}$ from $n=1$ to $\infty.$
Now, I have used the ratio test to get to a point of $ -2x/e^2$ which is great (and hopefully correct) but I for the life of me cannot work out how to calculate the actual interval of $R=...$
Can anyone a) tell me if my ratio test is correct, and b) help me with how to calculate $R=$
Thanks

Comment: Hint: (-2x)^n / e^(2n) = (-2x / e^2 )^n

Comment: Or the series has terms r^n, where r = -2x / e^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three different methods.

> **Using geometric series**
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n=1}^ {+\infty}\dfrac{(-2x)^n}{e^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^ {+\infty}\left(\dfrac{-2x}{e^{2}}\right)^n
> \end{equation}
> We must have:
> $$\left|\dfrac{-2x}{e^2}\right|<1 \implies -\dfrac{e^2}{2}<x<\dfrac{e^2}{2}$$

Rewriting the series as follows, we can apply other tests:
$$\sum_{n=1}^ {+\infty}\dfrac{(-2x)^n}{e^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^ {+\infty}\left(-\dfrac{2}{e^{2}}\right)^nx^n$$

> **Using D'Alembert test**
> $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left|\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{e^{2n+2}}\dfrac{e^n}{2^n}\right|=\dfrac{2}{e^2}:=l_1$$
> Now
> $$\rho=\dfrac{1}{l_1}=\dfrac{e^2}{2}$$

> **Using Cauchy-Hadamard test**
> $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(-\dfrac{2}{e^{2}}\right)^n \right|}=\dfrac{2}{e^2}:=l_2$$
> Now
> $$\rho=\dfrac{1}{l_2}=\dfrac{e^2}{2}$$

If $x=\pm \dfrac{e^2}{2}$, substituting in the initial sum we notice it diverges.

In conclusion:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^ {+\infty}\dfrac{(-2x)^n}{e^{2n}}}$ converges $ \iff x \in \left(-\dfrac{e^2}{2},\dfrac{e^2}{2}\right)$

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up working it out, so it was actually awesome to see that I did it correctly. I used the Geometric Series approach. Thank you for your help

Comment: Using geometric series when possible is a common trick, also D'alembert and Cauchy-Hadamard tests are very useful but remember you can apply them when you have a power series. Have a nice day!